# Stripping or duplicating ie8.js to fix just the button tag bugs

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am looking to just fix the `<button type=submit>` problem using the ie8.js, so I don't want the other stuff.

Anyone have any experience in either removing the unused functionality or replicating it in either pure javascript or since we use jQuery, that's fine too?

What I want to avoid is unintended performance hits from all of the other things the library trying to fix up my pages in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [src directory](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc) at the code repo, you'll find the individual bits that go into putting the full distribution together. Rummage around and you'll eventually find which is responsible for the fix you want. (Sorry I can't be more specific, but I haven't had to resort to these libs for a while.)

There are pretty much certainly going to be dependencies, so be prepared to still need to grab several files. Then take those and combine them into a single one for convenience.

It'll still probably have some extra stuff beyond that single feature, as the files are groups of conceptually-related functions, but I would *not* recommend actually going in and trying to hack Dean's code unless you know exactly what you're doing.